# STL map Custom Key Class [default constructor]

Tags: c++, graph, stl, stdmap

I have a graph implementation with a Node class like below

```
class Node {
public:
    Node() : idx(0), volume(1.0), futureVol(1.0), isCoarse(false) { }
    Node(index n) : idx(n), volume(1.0), futureVol(1.0), isCoarse(false) { }
    Node(const Node& a) : idx(a.idx), volume(a.volume), futureVol(a.futureVol), isCoarse(a.isCoarse) { }

    ...

    bool operator<(const Node& n) const {
        return futureVol > n.futureVol;
    }
    bool operator==(const Node& n) const {
        return idx > n.idx;
    }

    Node& operator=(const Node& node){
        if(this != &node){
            futureVol = node.futureVol;
            volume = node.volume;
            isCoarse = node.isCoarse;
            idx = node.idx;
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    index idx;
    double volume;
    double futureVol;
    bool isCoarse;
};
```

And a graph with the following implementation:

```
class Graph{
private:
    std::map<Node,std::vector<Node>> edges;
    std::map<index, std::map<index, edgeweight>> edgeWeights;
    std::map<index, Node> nodes;
    Graph(const Graph& g);
    Graph& operator=(const Graph& g);
    count numNodes;
public:
    Graph(count& n); //default
    ~Graph(); //destructor
    Graph(std::vector<Node>&);
    void print();
    const std::vector<Node> neighbors(const index& idx) const;
    const std::vector<Node> coarseNeighbors(const index& idx) const;
    void addEdge(index &node1, index &node2, edgeweight& weight);
    void addEdges(std::map<index, std::map<index, edgeweight> >& e );
    edgeweight weight(const index& idx, const index& idx2) const;
    edgeweight weightedDegree(const index& idx) const;
    count degree(const index& idx) const;
    std::map<index, Node>& getNodes(){return nodes;}
    const count getSize() const { return numNodes; }
};

#endif
```

And Graph.cpp:

```
#include "graph.h"
#include <algorithm>

Graph::Graph(count& n): 
edges(),
edgeWeights(),
nodes(),
numNodes(n)
{
    for(index i=0; i<numNodes;i++){
        Node n(i);
        nodes[i] = n;   
    }
}
...
void Graph::addEdge(index& n1, index& n2, edgeweight& weight){

    edgeWeights[n1][n2]= weight;
    edgeWeights[n2][n1]= weight;
    edges[nodes[n1]].push_back(nodes[n2]);
    edges[nodes[n2]].push_back(nodes[n1]);
}
...
```

The problem is whenever I add a new edge. The default constructor of Node is called and I end up having 0 as the node Id instead of the original node that was passed to `addEdge` e.g `addEdge(1,2,4.0)` would add edge 0 <--> 2 to the graph. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to write a custom hash function like below but it didn't help:

```
namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<Node>
    {
        size_t operator()(const Node& n) const
        {
            return (hash<float>()(n._index()) >> 1);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that all the `Nodes` associated with`index` are created when you call `AddEdge`, because `operator[]` of the map, return the value corresponding to the key provided or **insert a new `(key, newvalue)`, where `newvalue` is default constructed.**

Comment: I would take a look at `emplace()`.  You should be able to use that to add the objects to your map and construct them how you want to.

Comment: @NetVipeC Yes I verified all my nodes were created. I also understand that a newvalue is default constructed. However, in this case it is creating a new key by default.

Comment: All your nodes are equivalent to each other (as far as `map<Node, ...>` is concerned). They all have the same value of `futureVol`, and so none is less than any other. `edges[nodes[n1]]` and `edges[nodes[n1]]` both refer to the same map entry.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That pretty much fixed it. I changed it to index. If you post that comment as an answer, I'll accept it and vote on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that `std::map` uses `operator<`, never `operator==`. It considers two keys equivalent as long as `!(key1 < key2) && !(key2 < key1)`.

Your `Node::operator<` compares `futureVol`, which you never set to anything other than the default value of `1.0`, so all nodes your program creates are equivalent to each other, as far as `std::map<Node, ...>` is concerned. Thus, `edges` map only ever has one entry. When you write

```
edges[nodes[n1]].push_back(nodes[n2]);
edges[nodes[n2]].push_back(nodes[n1]);
```

both statements update that same entry.